# conversion from basic type to user defined type

Tags: c++, oop

If we have a user defined type (class) named `Distance`, and `dist1` and `dist2` as objects of that type, then we can perform:

```
dist1=dist2;
```

As the compiler provides a built-in assignment operator.

But, at the same time, we can also perform this:

```
dist1= 1.0;
```

How does the compiler do that conversion from `float` to `Distance`, as I think there could only be one copy of implicit assignment which will have the same class as argument.

`Distance` has the following constructors:

```
Distance()
Distance(float c)
```

Comment: Show how `Distance` is defined.

Comment: i added the information

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is the use of a [Converting Constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) for the Distance type.

Basically, if you declare a constructor for a type `T` for a type that:

- takes one argument of type `S` (or a reference to `S`)
- is not declared `explicit`

then the compiler is allowed to automatically convert the `S` into a `T` by calling that constructor. So, if you had a function that took a T:

```
void do_the_thing(T const& t);
```

Then the two calls would be equivalent (assuming there is not also an overload of `do_the_thing` that takes `S` as an argument):

```
T t;
S s;

do_the_thing(t);
do_the_thing(T(s));
```

So your second line is more or less equivalent to the following:

```
{
    Distance temp(1.0);   
    dist1 = temp;
    // temp goes out of scope and is destroyed
}
```

Comment: ya i have added the missing constructors there in the question and it is indeed what u say.thank you

Comment: had we define an assignment operator overload in our class having float argument it would have executed to solve the purpose right

Comment: It's worth noting that a converting constructor need not have just a single argument. It just needs the other arguments defaulted.

Comment: Yes, declaring `Distance& operator=(float v)` would cause it to be used instead of a temporary variable being created.

Comment: actually we only need one argument in this particular case.Its being converted from meter to inch and float.Although u r correct logically

Comment: As an example of the converting constructor thing, see the following: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GdM0mn